# PySpark -Streaming- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I'm submitting a PySpark Streaming Job in a `kubernetes` environment. The job consumes data from kafka and process it using pyspark.

Spark version : 3.2.1,
Apache Kafka version : 2.4

**I submit using the below `spark-submit` command:**

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
     --master k8s://https://test.containers.cloud.ibm.com:35000 \
     --deploy-mode cluster \
     --name spark-streaming-su \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-streaming-driver-su \
     --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=test-spark \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=/code-volume/upload_path \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile=/etc/spark-secret/ca.crt \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile=/etc/spark-secret/token \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=2 \
     --conf spark.driver.memory=2g \
     --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4 \
     --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
     --conf spark.executor.memory=2g \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores=1 \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.pyspark.pythonVersion=3 \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=us.ic.io/test/spark-test:v5 \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets=test-us-icr-io \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.pvc-567yun-4b67-389u-9cfg1-gtabd234567.options.claimName=pvc-code \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.pvc-567yun-4b67-389u-9cfg1-gtabd234567.mount.path=/code-volume \
     /code-volume/test/test_streaming.py
```

**error:**

> Error occured due to : An error occurred while calling o60.load. :
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:599)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.(KafkaSourceProvider.scala)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaSourceProvider$$validateStreamOptions(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:338)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.sourceSchema(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:71)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:236)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:118)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:118)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:34)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.loadInternal(DataStreamReader.scala:167)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:143)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer     at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)     ... 22 more

I tried with the following addition in the spark submit. But none worked

**Trial 1)**

```
--jars "/opt/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar,/opt/spark/jars/kafka-clients-2.4.0.jar,/opt/spark/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar"
```

**Trial 2)**

```
 --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/opt/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar:/opt/spark/jars/kafka-clients-2.4.0.jar:/opt/spark/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar" \
 --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar:/opt/spark/jars/kafka-clients-2.4.0.jar:/opt/spark/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar" \
```

**Trial 3)**

```
 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.1
```

Comment: `kafka-clients` is what you need.. Make sure it's version is the same as what's actually needed by the sql-kafka one, not your Kafka server version. And you shouldn't need both streaming and structured streaming jars

Comment: Have you tried including the kafka-clients in the packages argument? Otherwise, both 1 and 2 are needed together, but for (2) I don't think /opt/spark/jars is the location of the uploaded `--jars` inside your pods, as (1) refers to the local filesystem where you run Spark submit

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer , when I copied all relavant jars in a PVC folder and used both "jars" and "classPath" together, it worked

Options:
______
     --jars "/code-volume/extrajars/*" \
     --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/code-volume/extrajars/* \
     --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/code-volume/extrajars/* \

Comment: Feel free to put that as a full answer below. Also, the driver shouldn't need more jars than what's included in spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded `elastic-jars`, `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar` and it's dependencies and made it available in "`/code-volume/extrajars/`" .

**Note**: as per OneCricketeer's comment , the below should be used together.

```
 --jars "/code-volume/extrajars/*" \
 --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/code-volume/extrajars/* \
 --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/code-volume/extrajars/* \
```

### Working spark-submit command:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
     --master k8s://https://test.containers.cloud.ibm.com:35000 \
     --deploy-mode cluster \
     --name spark-streaming-su \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-streaming-driver-su \
     --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=test-spark \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=/code-volume/upload_path \
     --jars "/code-volume/extrajars/*" \
     --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/code-volume/extrajars/* \
     --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/code-volume/extrajars/* \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile=/etc/spark-secret/ca.crt \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile=/etc/spark-secret/token \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=2 \
     --conf spark.driver.memory=2g \
     --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4 \
     --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
     --conf spark.executor.memory=2g \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores=1 \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.pyspark.pythonVersion=3 \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=us.ic.io/test/spark-test:v5 \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets=test-us-icr-io \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.pvc-567yun-4b67-389u-9cfg1-gtabd234567.options.claimName=pvc-code \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.pvc-567yun-4b67-389u-9cfg1-gtabd234567.mount.path=/code-volume \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.pvc-567yun-4b67-389u-9cfg1-gtabd234567.options.claimName=pvc-code \
     --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.pvc-567yun-4b67-389u-9cfg1-gtabd234567.mount.path=/code-volume \
     /code-volume/test/test_streaming.py
```